# Sharepoint include javascript to all site levels. SharePoint:ScriptLink

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I need to add javascript for my masterpage.
In package i added folder Layouts\ProjectName\custominit.JS
Then i add ScriptLink to my masterpage:

But have a problem, becouse script is visible only on subsites:

http://localhost/subsite/

The top level site generate error
"File not found"!

```
    Unexpected  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file / does not exist.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpCo... 058b0aff-0b84-4fb9-a86d-07a77a3ebada
02/11/2011 14:17:39.00* w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ntext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CmsVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(...  058b0aff-0b84-4fb9-a86d-07a77a3ebada
02/11/2011 14:17:39.00* w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)     at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  058b0aff-0b84-4fb9-a86d-07a77a3ebada
02/11/2011 14:17:39.00  w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://localhost:80/SitePages/Home.aspx)). Execution Time=13.2701223200155    058b0aff-0b84-4fb9-a86d-07a77a3ebada
02/11/2011 14:17:40.49  w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://localhost:80/_layouts/help.aspx?Lcid=1033&Key=WSSEndUser_troubleshooting&ShowNav=true))    
02/11/2011 14:17:40.49  w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://localhost:80/_layouts/help.aspx?Lcid=1033&Key=WSSEndUser_troubleshooting&ShowNav=true) 842cff7a-417a-49ef-8c54-d795bc5f5ccf
02/11/2011 14:17:40.51  w3wp.exe (0x1A68)                           0x1290  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  842cff7a-417a-49ef-8c54-d795bc5f5ccf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because you need to apply that masterpage which you customised to all sites (do it from Site collection level then make all subsites inherit).

Comment: All subsites alredy with custom masterpage. On subsites script is running. But on main level shows "File not found". Masterpage without javascript running without problems

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like the [Free SharePoint Infuser](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/07/massage-sharepoint-into-submission.html) to automatically inject JavaScript in all pages of a site collection?